# Crawled - currently not indexed after removing www from domain

Tags: google-search-console

I am running a Woocommerce based website which had the address `http://www.example.com`. I then removed *www* as Adsense will not let me register the site. After that, I add new items but GSC keeps saying *crawled but not index* I see many such pages in the report including the new one which never existed before and was added recently. It's been weeks! How do I fix this issue and let Google crawl my newly added category?

Comment: What type of property do you have in Google Search Console?  Is it a domain property or a prefix property?  If prefix, what is the prefix?  What is an example of a URL you are testing in GSC?  With or without the www?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Not sure how I skilled the comment. It is not domain based I believe because I did not make any DNS changes. The older property was based on _www.example.com_. I then made changes in Wordpress and changed `www.example.com` URL to `example.com`. The property in GSC was earlier based on `www.example.com`, I removed and create  new properly with name `example.com`.

Comment: I wouldn't remove the property.  It is better to have multiple prefix properties in GSC for all the variations.

Comment: Can you answer my other questions?  What is an example of a URL you are testing in GSC? With or without the www?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller `http://nisaa.pk/product-category/brands/` It is crawled but not index. There are many others

Comment: @StephenOstermiller did you find some clue? kindly guide.